# Controle WebBrowser acumulando memória a cada utilização do método Navigate

Tags: c#, memória, navegador-de-internet

Criei um programa que utiliza o WebBrowser para buscar informações online (Realizar login automático e posteriormente trazer as informações da página para o programa).
O programa funciona perfeitamente, mas acontece que o programa atualiza as informações a cada 5 minutos e, então, acaba utilizando o método Navigate a cada 5 minutos.

`WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com", false);`

Acima está um exemplo.
Toda a vez que utilizo o método Navigate a memória aumenta e não importa o que eu faça ela não diminui.
Tentei utilizar o método Dispose, tentei deletar o controle... Tudo sem sucesso.
OBS.: Usando Dispose a memória diminui, mas sempre sobra um pouco a mais na memória e, por conta disso, ainda assim acaba acumulando memória.

Alguém saberia alguma forma de evitar esse aumento de memória a cada utilização do método Navigate?

Comment: Já tentou instanciar sua variável webBrowser1 apenas se ela não estiver instanciada?

Comment: Talvez torná-la estática?

Comment: Apresente o código de como você está implementando e as evidências do consumo de memória.

Comment: Se está sempre a instanciar um novo objeto, é normal que a memória aumente. Tente tornar isso um objeto global, sendo instanciado apenas uma vez.

Comment: Instancio apenas uma vez, como no exemplo.

Comment: Editei o comentário anterior no mesmo dia, mas acho que não salvou...
Enfim, eu crio uma instancia global e depois apenas uso o método Navigate a cada intervalo de tempo e a memória acumula.
Se eu utilizo Dispose a memória diminui, mas fica uma "sobra" de memória.